# Agora Web SDK enableLogUpload not working

Tags: javascript, agora.io

I'm trying to get data logged to console by Agora web sdk 3.6.9. Docs saying there is [enableLogUpload](https://docs.agora.io/en/Interactive%20Broadcast/API%20Reference/web/modules/agorartc.logger.html#enablelogupload) method but it's not showing me anything in Agora dashboard or I don't use it correct way.
Here's my code:

```
<script src="AgoraRTCSDK-3.6.9.js"></script>
<script>
    AgoraRTC.Logger.setLogLevel(AgoraRTC.Logger.DEBUG);
    AgoraRTC.Logger.enableLogUpload();

    //rtc options, connection, etc.
</script>
```

I can see requests in network tab of devtools to `https://logservice.agora.io/upload/v2` with needed data but it's unavailable at agora's dashboard.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [enableLogUpload](https://docs.agora.io/en/Interactive%20Broadcast/API%20Reference/web/modules/agorartc.logger.html#enablelogupload) method is used to send logs to the Agora Server to debug potential problems, if you want to maintain the application logs for yourself you can use a different service like [datadog](https://www.datadoghq.com/)

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks for your response. I've ended up with redefining standard `console.log()`.